# Unwanted white areas on HTML page

Tags: html, css

I've made a site using with a CSS made from scratch.

[The Page](http://defjam64.site40.net/stackoverflow/so1.html) [The CSS](http://defjam64.site40.net/stackoverflow/so1css.css)

Randomly there are unwanted white spaces in two places:

- Above the main content area (below
     the menu bar).
- Below the main content area  and
     sidebar and above the footer.

I've experimented with various methods of fixed the problem like margins and paddings but they didn't seem to work.

What could I do to get rid of these white areas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra white space comes from the browser's default stylesheet. Add these rules:

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To solve this problem, and prevent future ones, I recommend using a CSS reset. [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a widely recommended one; another good option is the [YUI CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/).

Comment: +1, with caveat that you may generally want space above/below a real heading, so in some cases you might just want to specify which headings you *don't* want a top/bottom margin on. Like `.maincontent h2 { margin-top: 0; }`, etc.

Comment: @anonymous: the typical use case is to just reset everything, and then build up your CSS as needed.

Comment: There are many, including myself, that believe CSS resets are useless at best.  What is the purpose for undoing everything in order to set necessary styling?  Twice the work with no benefit.  If you need to change a margin then change it.  There is no benefit in zeroing everything and then resetting what shouldn't have been zeroed.

Comment: @mark: there's no objectively correct answer to the question "Should I use a CSS reset?" As a matter of personal preference, I like to use them.

Comment: It seems that CSS resets are good but they could easily cause possible problems.A tough dilemma.Thanks to all for the suggestions and for the introduction to CSS resets.

Comment: @Matt I agree, and that is also *my* typical use case, as well as having a margin above or below my headers in almost all cases. Just figured it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

You need a css reset. For example the white space below the menu bar is caused by the browser default margins of the `.maincontent h2`.

Personally I prefer to reset the styles for the selectors that I use, but there are general css resets like [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I added in:`.menubar h2 { float:left; margin:0px; padding:0px; }` Yet the white space above the main content area still exists.

Comment: @Adam Sorry, I was talking about the h2 of `.maincontent`, I hadn´t realized that the whole menu was made up of h2's...

Comment: No problem but your idea of a reset CSS was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your maincontent h2 and footer h4 both have margins(.83em and 1.33 em respectively) set them both to 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out your css in IE?

`.maincontent {
background: #0F3;
height: 300px;
width: 580px;
float: left;
}`

basically, you need to add `float:left;` to your maincontent css

Answer (score 0):

1.) The "Main Page" header has a top margin of 19 pixels. This causes that 19 pixel area of white space.
2.) The entire Footer has a top margin of 21 pixels. This causes that 21 pixel area of white space. Also, for fixing the issue below sidebar, solving 1 + 2 may automatically resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to the top of your stylesheet:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, p
{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

This ensures that all browsers' default padding/margin are set to 0, so its consistent. Then you can add padding/margin where you need it.